# How is it possible to add additional product images without replacing existing using woo commerce rest api in python

Tags: python, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I am using the version=”wc/v3″, of the woocommerce rest api.

I want to add additional image(s) to a product , without the new images overwriting the old.

I am using the api in Python.

Ex:

```
old_images = [“1” , “2”]

new_images = [“3” , “4”]
```

after updating the product the final list is :

```
final_list = [“3” , “4”]
```

but i want to be :

```
final_list = [“1” , “2”, “3” , “4”]
```

**Is it possible to achieve to upadate my list in this way?**

My code:

```
def update_woocommerce_product_individually(wcapi,mixed_name,fetched_sku,short_description,description,woo_commerce_category_id,post_id,photo_gallery_dictionary_list):
    data = {
    "name":mixed_name,
    "short_description":short_description,
    "description":description,
    "images":photo_gallery_dictionary_list
}
    wcapi.put("products/"+str(post_id), data).json()
```

The `photo_gallery_dictionary_list` variable is holding the new_images = [“3” , “4”]

Comment: You can create `photo_gallery_dictionary_list` as `old_images.extend(new_images)`

Comment: @Gabip I want the extension to happen in property images of product in my wordpress site. Your answer is correct but python based. If i do that with woo commerce rest api the final_list will be the extended but the old_images items will stored twice in my wordpress media gallery